# "Come up in the next half hour"

Tags: phrase-meaning

I often hear the phrase "(something) coming up in the next half hour" when I hear a radio. "(something)" means a specific piece of news there.

As far as I understand that phrase is used to introduce what we will hear in the next half an hour. But, according to **[this](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/search/?direct=1&multi=1&dictCode=english&q=come%20up)** definition it's a bit strange, I mean how can we ever relate "unexpectedly appeared" to that context?

Comment: come up could be used with more than 15 meanings or definitions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at definition 1.1 on that same [page](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/come-up?q=come+up):

> **come up**: (Of a specified time or event) **approach** or **draw near**: *she’s got exams coming up*

In this definition, the time is known and the event is expected. This definition applies to the context of a radio announcer saying *(some news item) is coming up in the next half hour*.

Comment: Let me ask why do you replace my _couple unexpectedly appeared event with_ to your _relate "unexpectedly appeared" to_? Does the phrase make no sense?

Comment: To my American English ear, the wording was unnatural. I tried hard to stay with what I thought you intended to say. "Couple" often means to "join" two objects or distinct ideas. "Relate" is more natural in this context. Here, [relate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/relate) is _to show or establish logical or causal connection between_. Other possible word choices here include "associate ... with" and "understand ... in". I couldn't figure out how to make "event" sound natural without more extensive changes. No offense intended.

Answer (score 1):

Look at Definition 1.1 and the three example sentences. Doesn't the third example seem to be a parallel to the "something's coming up in the next thirty minutes" radio example. This definition talks about the approach of a specified (Cf. *specific*)  event.

By the way, don't get confused by the use of the word *something* in the first definition. *Something* refers to a specific item or topic ("piece of news") in both the first definition and the "sub-definition" 1.1.

If the radio announcer actually uses the word *something,* he or she is still referring to a specific piece of news. It is just that the announcer has not referred to it by name... maybe to keep the listeners in suspense so that they will continue to listen to the show.